# Another word for "acceptable"

Tags: synonyms

What is a better word to describe "acceptable"?

For example, I want to say: "this result may well provide an acceptable measurement of health". I could use "good", "new",... but I want to express a humble idea of just creating a new variable that could be used widely later on in research...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just don't use "appropriate", which is so overused that it has become meaningless.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/acceptable?s=t

Comment: What about "reliable" ?

Comment: You can try using "proper", but maybe in slightly different context.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Maybe ***reasonable***

Comment: How completely do you want to claim that the variable captures "health," and how are you defining "health," anyway?

Comment: i think i will use "appropriate" :) but will use all your suggested words throughout my paper in order to avoid repetation:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*satisfactory*:

1. Giving satisfaction

   "satisfactory living conditions"; "his grades were satisfactory"
2. Meeting requirements

   "the step makes a satisfactory seat";

   - **acceptable**

-- [WordWeb, satisfactory](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=satisfactory). See also [WordWeb, acceptable](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=acceptable)